# How to fix 'procedural skybox' visible horizon line on 'screen space camera' canvas?

Tags: unity, skybox

I can see the horizon line through my screen space camera canvas.

Here are the steps to reproduce it for 2019.3.0f3:

1. create a new scene
2. create a new material for the Skybox

   - set shader to Skybox/Procedural
   - set Atmosphere Thickness to 4
3. open Window/Rendering/Lighting Settings

   - set Skybox Material to material created in step 2
   - click Auto Generate at bottom
4. in Hierarchy add a new UI/Panel

   - set canvas Render Mode to Screen Space - Camera
   - assign the main camera to Render Camera
   - set panel image color to non-transparent white
5. set main camera rotation to 15, 15, 15

The resulting artifacts:
[image]

The canvas has been disabled, for reference:
[image]

This problem starts appearing when atmosphere thickness is > 3, currently I need 4.

**How can this be fixed, if at all ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by copying the shader from builtin shaders and added `ZTest Equal`.